# Only first button in layout is using state selector

Tags: android

Why does only the first button in this layout use the selector I've defined?

I haven't included the selector and it's various styles and drawables, since the first button works correctly so I assume that the problem is not with the selector.

The `onClickListener`s work fine on all of the buttons.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:background="#ffffff"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/copyLabel"
            android:background="@color/backgroundblue"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <TextView
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="@string/copy"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:text="Notepad &amp; system"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/SNS"
            style="@style/button"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/sc_cut"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:text="Single"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <View
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/lightgray"/>

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/DNS"
            style="@style/button"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/sc_cut"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:text="Dual"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <View
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/lightgray"/>

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/TNS"
            style="@style/button"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/sc_cut"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:text="Table"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/sysLabel"
            android:background="@color/backgroundblue"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <TextView
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:text="@string/copy"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ssLabel"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:text="System"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/SS"
            style="@style/button"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/sc_cut"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:text="Single"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <View
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/lightgray"/>


    <Button
            android:id="@+id/DS"
            style="@style/button"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/sc_cut"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:text="Dual"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <View
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/lightgray"/>


    <Button
            android:id="@+id/TS"
            style="@style/button"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/sc_cut"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:text="Table"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <View
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/lightgray"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're specifying a background color for the other buttons. Presumably this overwrites the background drawable specified in the style.

Comment: Wow.   How did I miss that? (probably because it was 15 hours into the coding session :)).  Thank you.